# Write permissions for the device in android 14

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-permissions

In android 14 WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not working, So what can be used instead of that permission ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Its not even needed/usable on Android 14+ devices.

Comment: I mean WRITE_STORAGE_PERMISSION is not allowed to use in android 14. So that, is there any other permission for the write in storage ?

Comment: @Udishan MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is the new permission. But be aware that you can use it mostly for personal or internal projects as play store won't accept apps that include it unless they are explicitly a file-manager.

Answer (score 2):

On Android 14 devices your app by default has write permissions in app specific directories like those from getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and also in all public directories on external storage.

Use

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...).
```